# Alterar background do PDF de acordo com os dados do banco (PHP, MYSQL, FPDF)

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

Estou tentando personalizar o meu relatório em `FPDF`, trata-se de um sistema que gera ticket's de desconto, onde são impressos por lotes, por exemplo lote de 50 unidades.
Os tickets desse lote irão possuir o mesmo perfil onde pode ser 10%, 20% e 30% de desconto.
Gostaria de personalizar o background de acordo com o perfil.

Gostaria de saber o perfil de apenas um dos ticket's para fazer a comparação já que o perfil é o mesmo para todos do lote

```
$result_tickets = "SELECT * FROM vouchers WHERE serial_lote = '112027511417'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result_tickets);

$registros = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

////ME VEIO ESTA IDEIA, PORÉM NÃO ESTÁ FUNCIONANDO..

$perfil_desconto = $resultado['desconto'];
if ($perfil_desconto == '10%') {

   $template_background = "template-10.jpg";

} elseif ($perfil_desconto == '20%') {

   $template_background = "template-20.jpg";

}  elseif ($perfil_desconto == '30%') {

   $template_background = "template-30.jpg";

}  elseif ($perfil_desconto == '50%') {

   $template_background = "template-50.jpg";

} 

$pdf = new Fpdf ('p','mm','A4');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','','10');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image("$template_background", 0,0,210,295);
```

Lembrando que ainda tem o While que puxa todos os dados do banco e os insere no PDF, mas não achei necessário inserir aqui.

Comment: Porque  você diz que não está funcionando? Não está vindo o conteúdo por completo?

Comment: @AndreiCoelho veja bem, tudo está ok.. quero apenas personalizar a folha de acordo com o perfil.. algo do tipo: Case (perfil)

Comment: @AndreiCoelho está certa sim, é uma url, então é necessário.

Comment: É que eu ainda não entendi a pergunta direito. O perfil que você está falando é do desconto? Perfil x é 20%, perfil y é 30%, é isso?

Comment: @AndreiCoelho exatamente, cada impressão pega um lote, esse lote tem ticket's de apenas um perfil, preciso usar um template para cada perfil.

Comment: `$template_voucher = "template-10.jpg";` Essa variável está certa? Ou seria `template_background `?

Comment: @AndreiCoelho isso, na verdade no momento que postei minha pergunta devo ter inserido errado, tiz algumas edições.. vou corrigir.

Comment: Tranquilo. O erro é que não está gerando o PDF. É isso?

Comment: @AndreiCoelho  está gerando tudo normal, só que estou usando o mesmo fundo (Background) para todos os perfis.... saca?  O que estou tentando fazer e usar uma imagem de fundo diferente para cada perfil.

Comment: Entendi agora. Vou formular uma resposta.

Comment: Cada voucher é uma folha A4? Ou cabem mais? Tipo, cada folha A4 são 4 voucher.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho em cada folha A4 vem 10 vouchers tem duas colunas, 5 de cada lado, porém precisaria verificar o perfil de apenas um para identificar já que todos os do lote são do mesmo perfil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está nesta linha `$perfil_desconto = $resultado['desconto'];`. Você não consegue identificar pois a variável `$resultado` está relacionada ao objeto da query.

Uma opção seria adicionar o `mysqli_fetch_array` fazer isso:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result_tickets);

$registros = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

$reg = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado); // aqui eu adicionei

////ME VEIO ESTA IDEIA, PORÉM NÃO ESTÁ FUNCIONANDO..

$perfil_desconto = $reg['desconto'];
if ($perfil_desconto == '10%') {

   $template_background = "template-10.jpg";

} elseif ($perfil_desconto == '20%') {

   $template_background = "template-20.jpg";

}  elseif ($perfil_desconto == '30%') {

   $template_background = "template-30.jpg";

}  elseif ($perfil_desconto == '50%') {

   $template_background = "template-50.jpg";

}
```

Se não for isso, comente aqui.

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso! Valeu jovem!